# How to write Dynamic c# code when views not inherited by browser in Razor MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to know how i can use Dynamic c# whenever i not inherited my views by model.

are their any way to write dynamic c# in views whenever i use Razor.

like how i can write razor code who match this aspx cod

```
<% List<item> items = new List<item>(); %>
```

how i can write this in my MVC 3 application views [razor]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@{
    List<item> items = new List<item>();
}
```

Scott Gu has a full coverage about [razor syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).

Comment: Im using aspx i tried  **<%if (ViewBag.AdminImage != null) %>**
     and the above thing but is not working in aspx, please could u help

Answer (score 8):

Basic rule of thumb:

<%= %> becomes @(   )

and

<% %> becomes @{    }